# why viewWillAppear does not get called?

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller, viewwillappear

```
[self.view addSubview:self.ListNewController.view];
```

as we know that function means, will add view to self.view.. the question is, why listNewController's viewWillAppear doesn't called?

is there any way to make animate change and call viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 1):

I think on iOS 5.0 and greater viewWillAppear gets called. But before viewWillAppear was only part of the UINavigationController's view lifecycle, in the sense that viewWillAppear and similar methods will be called only when you do things like pushViewController:animated:

So what you want to do is either put your code in viewDidLoad, or call viewWillAppear manually.